# Capped Water Heater Pressure Relief Extension Pipe

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, pipe

The answer seems fairly obvious, but maybe I am wrong.  Many water heaters have extension pipes plumbed into the pressure relief valves.  I'm assuming that this is to keep hot water from spraying around if the valve opens:
[image: T&P Water Heater Extension]

On the water heater in my garage, the pipe runs to a little bit above the floor and then ends.  This seems like the normal correct way to do this.  At my uncle's house, however, I noticed that the plumber soldered a cap on the end of the extension pipe.  This seems not only wrong, but potentially dangerous as the valve will simply open into a closed pipe which has no way to actually relieve the pressure of the valve it was installed for in the first place.
Is this as wrong as it seems, or a completely normal installation?

Answer (score 3):

The temperature and pressure relief valve, and any piping it is connected to (copper or CPVC only, at least 3/4" ID), should never be blocked, capped, or obstructed. You should remove that cap because, as you correctly surmised, it is a danger if the T&P valve were to open. A simple tubing cutter like the one shown below will work just fine to cut that cap off.

[image: Home Depot]

A note on your install, or at least the install depicted in the picture - the T&P discharge pipe should not terminate inside the drain pan. It should terminate no more than 6" above a properly-sized floor drain, or outside (unless freezing is a concern, then you should drain it inside).

Your water heater manual specifies all of these instructions as well.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the drain pan.  I actually just grabbed that picture off of google just to illustrate what I was talking about.